# Charts for iOS on CocoaPods: Swift Syntax Error

Tags: ios, xcode, charts, cocoapods

## The following problem appears to not occur on Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002), but is a show-stepper on 8.3 beta (8W109m).

A project I am writing includes the [Charts for iOS](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library via Cocoapods.

Here is my Podfile:

```
target 'v5snapp' do
    use_frameworks!
    
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Charts'
    pod 'GLCalendarView', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'
    pod 'RNCryptor-objc'
end

# I haven't needed this code for a while now
#post_install do |installer|
#    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
#            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
#        end
#    end
#end
```

In the Charts library, all of a sudden, there is a breaking change in the code. So, now that project won't compile, which shuts down building my whole project. Bummer.

Here is the function with the breaking code:

```
open override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    if object == nil
    {
        return false
    }
    
    if !(object! as AnyObject).isKind(of: type(of: self))
    {
        return false
    }
    
    // This is the breaking code. The problem seems to be this:
    // object! as AnyObject).data !== data
    if (object! as AnyObject).data !== data && !((object! as AnyObject).data??.isEqual(self.data))!
    {
        return false
    }
    
    if fabs((object! as AnyObject).y - y) > DBL_EPSILON
    {
        return false
    }
    
    return true
}
```

I don't write in Swift yet, and although most of it is pretty straightforward, I'm a little fuzzy on the `!`, `?`, and `===`/`!==` vs. `==`/`!=` stuff. So, what's wrong with the Swift code as-is? How can I fix it for my project? I'm tempted to just delete the offending code (leaving the other half of the line) until the library gets updated. As popular as it is, I'm sure I'm not the only one having this issue. I haven't seen this as an issue yet on the GitHub repo. I was hoping to figure out the fix myself (or here) before posting it as an issue there. Seems like just a simple problem. In the meantime, I'll go back to Xcode 8.2.1, but my devices are now on iOS 10.3 Beta, which makes it a pain to not be able to push directly to them over the wire.